# How to add a cell range, then divide the sum by 1 cell.

Tags: google-spreadsheets

How do I add cell range of BC3:BG3, then divide by cell BC3. Then I need to turn that answer into a percentage.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
=SUM(BC3:BG3)/BC3
```

Then click the [Format as percentage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaw6T.png) on the results cell.

It is not exactly described what you want to achieve, but consider that this will always be more than 100% if you are dividing by one of the added values.

Hope it helps.